# Is it justified to delete everything in the build folder before calling cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am now using cmake to compile and build a C++ project on multiple platforms. Every time the cmake script is called, everything in the building folder is deleted. For example, I use the following shell command to illustrate the way how cmake is called:

```
rm -rf build_folder
mkdir build_folder
cd build_folder
cmake ..
```

By doing so, we are sure that the library or binary produced by the project is updated with regard to the source code. However, it may take time as every time camke will call the compiler to build the project from scratch. The reason lies in the fact that we are concerned that cmake may keep some intermediate results from the previous build if we do not delete everything in the building folder. So my question is: are our concerns justified and if just call `cmake ..` in the previous building folder without deleting anything in the folder what kind of danger can we have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A major point of using a build system is not having to rebuild everything every time. A correct build system correctly tracks which files have changed and what commands are therefore necessary to do a correct, minimal rebuild.

If that doesn't work for you, you have messed up your build system.

If you are worried about doing builds for different platforms, and the build system not recognizing the difference, that's just one way your build system is messed up. Specifically, the problem is that you are building different variants, sequentially, in the same directory. At least that's what I take from your description. That's stupid, don't do it. Use a different build folder for every platform, call cmake once in each folder with the correct configuration, and then leave it be.

Comment: I would argue that for productions builds it can't hurt and should probably be cleaning out the build folder beforehand. It shouldn't hurt compile times since you will be doing production builds from scratch anyway.

Comment: @sjdowling True, for release packaging you generally want to force clean builds.